# Set up nodemailer before deployment with heroku

Tags: heroku, nodemailer

I am using nodemailer on a project and I am wondering what is the best way to secure the password of my email address before deployment.
So far I have write the email address and the password in a separate file and I add this file to my gitignore.
Is it enough or is there a better way to do it?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research and tests here is what I have done:
I have created 2 files, one for development and one for production.
The file for development contain all the informations. The file for production contain only one object with the info like this:

```
{email: process.env.EMAIL}
```

Then I have created a third file:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  module.exports = require("./keys_prod");
} else {
  module.exports = require("./keys_dev");
}
```

Finally in heroku settings you just have to add every config vars.
So far it works really well and everything seems to be protected.
I hope it helps.